# What the best way to delete files by extension?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I am looking the best way to delete files from directory by extension.
I am planning to do it by date. But now, i am testing how it works.
This:

```
dir=/tmp/backup/

mask="jpeg jpg png gif bmp pdf"

for i in $mask; do
find $dir -name "*.$i" -type f -delete
done
```

Or this ?

```
find $dir \( -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \
                 -o -name "*.gif" -o -name "*.bmp" -o -name "*.pdf" \) -type f -delete
```

I wan to do it with min resources of machine and operation system. Maybe you know other ways to do it. Because i will delete one year old files. And it can call lags. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use:

```
# to ensure it doesn't return *.jpg if there is no .jpg file
shopt -s nullglob

# list all matching extension filea
echo *.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif,bmp,pdf}
```

When you are satisfied with the output, just replace `echo` by `rm`

---

However if you want to make use of a variable then store all extensions in a variable then use it like this with `find` command:

```
mask="jpeg jpg png gif bmp pdf"

find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\.("${mask// /|}")"
```